# Can I disable modules with mobile detection in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, mobile-devices, joomla-module, joomla3.3

I am using Joomla 3.3.6 and I have a mobile responsive site. But certain modules I'm using on the site I would like to either disable completely or changed with the site is being viewed with a mobile browser. Does anyone know any scripts or extension I can use with Joomla to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joomla 3 hide module just for mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095938/joomla-3-hide-module-just-for-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for like 5 seconds and I found this post [Joomla 3 hide module just for mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095938/joomla-3-hide-module-just-for-mobile-devices) which basically contains your problem